# How do I send a different param to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, jqgrid

I'm trying to develop dynamic jqgrid where all the fields are driven by database using stored procedure, this works fine but I'm having problem when it comes to save specific record when user edits on jqgrid. below my code so far..

### Javascript

```
colNames: colname,
          colModel: colmodel,                
          onSelectRow: function (id) { 
          if (id && id !== lastsel) {
             jQuery('#list2').restoreRow(lastsel);
             jQuery('#list2').editRow(id, true);
             lastsel = id;
          }
       },
       serializeRowData: function (postdata) {
       return { tab: $(".ui-state-active").attr("id"), Data: JSON.stringify(postdata) }
},
```

> **C#**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(string Data)
{            
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
   var formData = js.Deserialize<object>(Data) as IDictionary<string, object>;

   List<SqlParameter> SQLParm = new List<SqlParameter>(); 

   foreach (var item in formData)
   {
      if (item.Key != "oper")
      {
         SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
         param.ParameterName = "@" + item.Key;
         param.Value = item.Value;
         SQLParm.Add(param);
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Now I'm stuck because of dynamic jqgrid it returns various data which I created a list list then pass to SP but problem is how would store procedure will reckon this parameters?

is there alternative way I can do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure your problem is clear.  Are you saying that you are having type mismatches with your SQL columns and your JSON values?  For example, the JSON is populated with a string for a column where you need an integer (or vice versa)?  I would think that if you pass a properly typed model to the jqgrid it should maintain the typing when generating JSON.  What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Ultimately you shouldn't expect any incoming JSON to be valid.  You should deserialize to a strongly typed class instead of a Dictionary.  Then save that class to the DB by reading each property.  This way you can ensure your SQL parameters are always the proper type.

Comment: Thanks for reply..basically i have have jqgrid with tabs and each tab has different tables and im getting those data using stored procedure which is then used to build dynamic jqgrid but my problem is when saving specific record and passing back to stored procedure which hopefully can handle update for all the tables rather than crating different SP. hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your data is dynamic but you know what it *could* be (otherwise, how would your proc know what to do with it?). If so, you could use a table-valued parameter [TVP] (of a custom user table type that contains all the properties that the procedure may need to receive). Then you could just populate the properties that are applicable before sending to the stored proc.

More about TVPs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Usage:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Edit(string Data)
    {
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var formData = js.Deserialize<object>(Data) as IDictionary<string, object>;

    List<SqlDataRecord> sqlDataRecords = new List<SqlDataRecord>(); 

    foreach (var item in formData)
    {
        // Create sql data record with appropriate properties populated and add to list if applicable
    }

    SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter("YourTableTypeParamName", SqlDbType.Structured)
                        {
                            Value = sqlDataRecords,
                            TypeName = "dbo.YourTableType"
                        };

        SqlConnection conn = ... // define connection here
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                command.CommandText = "YourStoredProcedureName";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);

                using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Do something with results
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    return null;
}
```